# Facing an issue with protocol associatedType

Tags: ios, swift, swift-protocols, type-alias

I have a list of tableview view data where user can pick one item i'm using ZPPickerDataSource protocol as a datasource, there is no issue at this stage

```
public protocol ZPPickerDataSource: ZPSearchableDataSource {
    var uuID: String {get}
    var displayString: String {get}
}
```

In addition the UI has search funcitonality as well, i'm using ZPSearchableDataSource, ZPSearchable for that. ZPPickerDataSource protocol confirms to ZPSearchableDataSource.

```
public protocol ZPSearchableDataSource {
    var displayString: String {get}
}

public protocol ZPSearchable {
    associatedtype dataSourceType: ZPSearchableDataSource
    var searchableItems: [dataSourceType] {get}
    func search(keyword: String) -> [dataSourceType]
}

public extension ZPSearchable {
    func search(keyword: String) -> [dataSourceType] {
        return searchableItems.filter{$0.displayString.contains(keyword)}
    }
}
```

when i mentions **ZPSearchable** protocol's

```
typealias dataSourceType = ZPPickerDataSource
```

i'm getting an error like **Your controller does not confirms to protocol ZPSearchable**.

```
class MyPickerScreen: ZPSearchable {
    
    typealias dataSourceType = ZPPickerDataSource
    var searchableItems: [dataSourceType] {
        return []
    }
    
    var searchResults: [dataSourceType] = []
    func searchItem(namedLike searchQuery: String) {
        searchResults = search(keyword: searchQuery)
    }
    
}
```

P.S:
I've tried struct named **TestSource** as a data source. and i mentioned

```
typealias dataSourceType = TestSource
```

then the code compiles. seems it occurs only with protocol.

```
public struct TestSource: ZPPickerDataSource {
    public var uuID: String = ""
    public var displayString: String = ""
    public var sampleVar = ""
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Surprisingly, `ZPPickerDataSource` does not conform to `ZPSearchableDataSource`. Only concrete types conform to protocols. Protocols do not conform to protocols. See Hamish's answer in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33112559/protocol-doesnt-conform-to-itself) for why.

Because of this, your type alias:

```
typealias dataSourceType = ZPPickerDataSource
```

does not satisfy the constraint that `dataSourceType` must conform to `ZPSearchableDataSource`, so the associated type requirement is not met, so your type does not conform to the protocol `ZPSearchable`.

You must use a struct/class for the associated type. You seem to want to be able to use *any* `ZPPickerDataSource`. In that case, you can write a struct that conforms to `ZPPickerDataSource`, and write a function that converts from any `ZPPickerDataSource` to your struct:

```
struct AnyZPPickerDataSource: ZPPickerDataSource {
    let wrapped: ZPPickerDataSource
    
    var uuID: String { wrapped.uuID }
    var displayString: String { wrapped.displayString }
    
    init(_ dataSource: ZPPickerDataSource) {
        wrapped = dataSource
    }
}
```

Then you can do:

```
class MyPickerScreen: ZPSearchable {
    var searchableItems: [AnyZPPickerDataSource] = []
    
    typealias dataSourceType = AnyZPPickerDataSource
}
```

Now you can put any kind of `ZPPickerDataSource` into `searchableItems`, e.g.

```
searchableItems.append(AnyZPPickerDataSource(TestSource(...)))
```